# What is the probability of forming a triangle when choosing $3$ segments?

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

> We have $6$ segments with the following lengths: $1,2,6,9,10$ and
>    $11$. What is the probability of forming a triangle when choosing $3$
>    segments?

$3$ segments form a triangle if and only if the length of each one is less than the sum of others' length. The count of all possible variations is $C_6^3=\dfrac{6.5.4}{2.3}=20$. Now I am trying to count the variations which form a triangle. The only way that I found is to write all possible outcomes and see which do form a triangle $(6)$. Is there any better way to count it?

Comment: Come off it! There are not many to count. You obviously cannot use 1. You can only use 2 in 2,9,10 and 2,10,11. That just leaves 6,9,10 and 6,9,11 and 6,10,11 and 9,10,11.

Comment: I agree $240$ is too many to enumerate and assess them all.  But you can quickly eliminate many of the options and then only enumerate the remainder.  The first quick way to speed this up that I thought of, was to sum all the pairs - of which there are only $30$.  Then you can quickly eliminate any not having a partner less than or equal to the sum.

Comment: @samerivertwice 240? Where does that come from?

Comment: @almagest $6\times5\times4=240$ ;)  My bad.

Comment: @samerivertwice: You're counting the same river six times. There are $\binom63=40$ possible triangles.

Comment: @joriki I was counting how many 3-tuples there are to assess for triangularity.

Comment: @joriki ah, good point

Comment: @samerivertwice: If by "triangularity" you mean individual instances of the triangle inequality, then you were still counting the same river twice, as each of the $\binom63$ unordered $3$-tuples gives rise to $3$, not $6$ inequalities, so there are $120$ inequalities to check.

Comment: @joriki evidently my self-deprecating humour is a little too dry for some !)

Comment: @samerivertwice: Funny, just as I was making puns on your river-related name, I got an upvote for [my old answer to "How many unique outcomes can be made from the 12 river tiles in Carcassonne?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2924115). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort it. In your case it is sorted already 
$1,2,6,9,10,11$

Pick ending $11$ and start from $1$ and $10$. If it were $1+10>11$, we would have a triangle. It is not.

Pick the next after $1$. It is $2$. Try again $2+10>11$. We have a triangle, and this means that besides that one triangle all combinations in between $6+10$, $9+10$ form a triangle as well. That is $3$ triangles.

Since we have a triangle now pick the one before $10$, and that is $9$ and try again. $2+9>11$. It is not a triangle so pick the one after $2$ and that is $6$. $6+9>11$ and that is a triangle and since there is no number between $6$ and $9$ that is the only additional triangle.

With that we exhausted all triangles that may have the largest side $11$. Move to the lower one $10$ and repeat.

In general you have this scheme:

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{1} & 2 & 6 & 9 & \mathbf{10} & 11 &  & \\ 1 & \mathbf{2} & 6 & 9 & \mathbf{10} & 11 & \text{+} & 3\\ 1 & \mathbf{2} & 6 & \mathbf{9} & 10 & 11 &  & \\ 1 & 2 & \mathbf{6} & \mathbf{9} & 10 & 11 & \text{+} & 1\\ \mathbf{1} & 2 & 6 & \mathbf{9} & 10 &  &  & \\ 1 & \mathbf{2} & 6 & \mathbf{9} & 10 &  & \text{+} & 2\\ 1 & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{6} & 9 & 10 &  &  & \\ \mathbf{1} & 2 & \mathbf{6} & 9 &  &  &  & \\ 1 & \mathbf{2} & \mathbf{6} & 9 &  &  &  & \\ \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{2} & 6 &  &  &  &  & \\ \end{bmatrix} $$

That is making it $6$ out of $\binom{6}{3}=20$ and that is a probability of $\frac{3}{10}$